# Disable Select Box when text input changed

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with a dynamically created `Select Box` and two `Inputs` with the type `text`.

When the input text with the id FirstName has changed from blank I am trying to disable the select box. I think I'm close but my function doesn't seem to want to work.

I am sorry for all the noob questions.  I try to figure it out first, trying many different thoughts, then if that fails I research a lot and then when I give up I come here...lol this place is a great source of knowledge.

I hope one day I can help out back. Have tried on input and `onchange` but can't get my function to fire.  And as per usual chrome debugger is perfectly content.

I did not show the code for the select box but just know that its ID is "regulars"

```js
function regcheck() {
  if document.getElementById('FirstName').value == "" {
    document.getElementById('regulars').disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('regulars').disabled = true;
  };
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="FirstName" id="FirstName" value="" oninput="regcheck()" ;>
<br>
<input type="text" name="FirstSong#" value="">
```

Comment: don't forget to put () around your if statement.

Comment: Also nothing has the id regulars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
 function regcheck() {
      if (document.getElementById('FirstName').value === "") {
        document.getElementById('regulars').removeAttribute('disabled');
      } else {
        document.getElementById('regulars').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
      };
    }
```

```html
<select id="regulars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="text" name="FirstName" id = "FirstName" value="" oninput="regcheck()";><br>
<input type="text" name="FirstSong" value="">
```

Comment: Explain your answer please.

Comment: There is not much difference to the question. `select.disabled` is perfectly valid: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/disabled

Comment: Awesome that works but I am confused by the code.  why disabled, disabled and not just disabled.. going to fiddle with it and read about the setAttribute method that I didn't know existed till now...tysm

Comment: OK did some research an actually glad I learned about the method.  So if I am not mistaken disabled is in there twice because  the second disable  is actually disabling the first disable which is the elements current attribute...lol I hope thats right.

Comment: @TotalNoob html attributes have both keys and values
`removeAttribute` methods accepts one argument which is the key of the attribute that you want to remove
but `setAttribute` method accepts 2 argument first one is the key of the attribute you want to set and the second one is the value of that attribute
[setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) 
[removeAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/removeAttribute)

Answer (score 1):

Just like the comment said. The only thing missing with your code are the parenthesis in your condition. It's throwing an error because of that.

```html
<script>
function regcheck() {
  if (document.getElementById('FirstName').value == "") {
    document.getElementById('regulars').disabled = false;
  } else {
    document.getElementById('regulars').disabled = true;
  };
}
</script>

<select id="regulars">
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
  <option value="audi">Audi</option>
</select>
<br>
<input type="text" name="FirstName" id = "FirstName" value="" oninput="regcheck()";><br>
<input type="text" name="FirstSong" value="">
```

Comment: ty such a noob mistake...syntax..but chrome debugger ussually cries to me about my syntax but this time it had no errors....thats why I didn't even realize the brackets

Answer (score 1):

as other said your regulars checkbox and the parenthesis are missing in the example.
this would probably work

```
<html>
<body>
<form action="/action_page.php">
    <input type="text" name="FirstName" id = "FirstName" value="" oninput="regcheck()";><br>
    <input type="text" name="FirstSong#" value="">
    <input type="checkbox" id='regulars' checked>regulars<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>
  function regcheck(){
      if (document.getElementById('FirstName').value == "") {
          document.getElementById('regulars').disabled = false;
      }else{
          document.getElementById('regulars').disabled = true;
      };
  }
</script>
</body>
```

also it's better to put your JavaScript at the end of the page to make it work with rendered Dom

Comment: thanks for the alternative option will explore it...Ya I know my code was missing the select box code but I stated that in my question along with its ID being regulars...thanks again

Answer (score -1):

Sometimes, while dynamically changing DOM inside the document, It usually doesn't work.
Try out with Jquery "on" function. It may work.

Comment: jquery is not an answer for everything